# C# RegularExpressions Match

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm noob in C#. Can anyone help to pull out /a/b/c.swf from this data by C# code

```
<object width="663" height="466.752" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
      <param value="/a/b/c.swf" name="movie">
</object>
```

thank so much

Comment: IS this XML or just a random string?

Comment: it is html, i need to get the url of playing flash

Comment: I can support 'not a real question', or 'not constructive', but to apply 'too localized' to this question sets a precedent for the closing of _most_ regex questions.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx is a good starting point for getting a handle on regular expressions in .NET.

Comment: why to close? he just asks how to extract file name from given html text snippet, why do you think this is too localized?

Comment: how is this different from any 'how do I do this with regex' question?

Comment: @SamHolder agree, the question need to be edited, but not closed as localized

Comment: If you want a more involved answer on pulling out attributes from html nodes see my blog article: [C# Regex Linq: Extract an Html Node with Attributes of Varying Types](http://omegacoder.com/?p=512) HTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string regexPattern = @"<param\svalue=""(?<paramVal>[^""]*)""";
string stuffImLookingFor = Regex.Match(input, regexPattern).Groups("paramVal").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a RegEx to do it:

```
param value="([^"]+)
```

The first match group will return "/a/b/c.swf"

You can test regular expressions here [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx)